# Determining the size of virtual and physical memories.

Tags: memory, virtual-memory

In the case that a virtual memory address has a length of 40 bits, the physical memory address has a length of 28 bits, how can we find the size of the physical and virtual memories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is raise two to the number of bits of the memory address.

The virtual memory size is [image] bytes.

The physical memory size is [image] bytes.